# how to get just first entry of collection with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, article

[image]

a have a lot of articles under categories. like 3 articles under same title, after that 2 articles under same title and so one.

i'm building it with JQuery, and ist ok so. getting out each entry in array.
**Output** looks like:

```
1. Innere Unruhe, Angstgef�hle, Schlafst�rungen - ein Problem vieler Menschen
1. Innere Unruhe, Angstgef�hle, Schlafst�rungen - ein Problem vieler Menschen
1. Innere Unruhe, Angstgef�hle, Schlafst�rungen - ein Problem vieler Menschen
2. Gesunde und krankhafte Angst
2. Gesunde und krankhafte Angst
```

but i need it like **this**:

```
1. Innere Unruhe, Angstgef�hle, Schlafst�rungen - ein Problem vieler Menschen
2. Gesunde und krankhafte Angst
```

here is my jQuery:

```
var contentarticles = articles.contentarticles;
for (var i = 0; i < contentarticles.length; i++) {
    var article = contentarticles[i];
    var $articlesOutput = $([
        '<li><a href="/id=', article.id, '/step=', i+1, '">',
        article.title,
        '</li>'
    ].join(""));
    $("#articlesOutput").append($articlesOutput);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Html or fiddle available ?

Comment: no dont have it. iam getting data from database...

Comment: it is hole html for the output:  <ul id="articlesOutput">
                </ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple modification should avoid duplicates:

```
var contentarticles = articles.contentarticles,
    article,
    $out = $("#articlesOutput");
for (var i = 0; i < contentarticles.length; i++) {
    if (!article || article.title != contentarticles[i].title) {
        article = contentarticles[i];
        var articlesOutput = [
            '<li><a href="/id=', article.id, '/step=', i+1, '">',
            article.title,
            '</li>'
        ].join("");
        $out.append(articlesOutput);
    }
}
```